# Replay a particular type of event from eventstore

Tags: event-sourcing, eventstoredb

I am currently using the [Event Store](https://github.com/EventStore/EventStore) to handle my events. I currently need to replay a particular type of event as I have made changes in the way they are subscribed and written to DB.

Is this possible? If so, how can it be done? Thanks.

Comment: Replaying a particular event type makes little sense, what do you plan to do with other events that happen for the same objects but later in time?

Comment: I have modified the calculation that is happening before being stored to DB. Hence, I need to replay only those events.

Comment: You can subscribe to a `$et-YourEventType` stream and it will give you all events of a certain type.

Comment: But that would mean a separate subscription, which I am little bit hesitant to add

Answer (score 2):

You cannot tell EventStore to replay a specific event onto a persistent subscription because the point of the persistent subscription is to keep state for the subscribers.

To achieve this kind of fix you would really need a catch up application to do the work.

And really if you think about, if you replayed ALL the events to a new database then you would have the correct data in there?

So I have a console application that reuses the same logic as the persistent connection but the only difference is:

1. I change the target database connection string - So this would be a new Database or Collection (not the broken one)
2. It connects to EventStore and replays all the events from the start
3. It rebuilds the entire database to the correct state
4. Switch the business over to the new database

This is the point of EventStore - You just replay all the events to build any database at any time and it will be correct

Your persistent connections deal with new, incoming events and apply updates.

Answer (score 0):

If you enable $by_event_type projection than you can access that projection stream under

/streams/$et-{event-type}

https://eventstore.org/docs/projections/system-projections/index.html

Then you can read it using .net api if you wish.

Here is some code to get you started

```
      private static T GetInstanceOfEvent<T>(ResolvedEvent resolvedEvent) where T : BaseEvent
            {

                var metadataString = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(resolvedEvent.Event.Metadata);
                var eventClrTypeName = JObject.Parse(metadataString).Property(EventClrTypeHeader).Value;
                var @event = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(Encoding.UTF8.GetString(resolvedEvent.Event.Data), Type.GetType((string) eventClrTypeName));
                if (!(@event is BaseEvent))
                {
                    throw new MessageDeserializationException((string) eventClrTypeName, metadataString);
                }

                return @event as T;
            }

            private static IEventStoreConnection GetEventStoreConnection()
            {
                var connectionString = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["EventStore"].ConnectionString;
                var connection = EventStoreConnection.Create(connectionString);
                connection.ConnectAsync().Wait();
                return connection;
            }

            private static string GetStreamName<T>() where T : BaseEvent
            {
                return "$et-" + typeof(T).Name;
            }
```

And to read events you can use this code snippet

```
 StreamEventsSlice currentSlice;
            long nextSliceStart = StreamPosition.Start;
            const int sliceCount = 200;

            do
            {
                currentSlice = await esConnection.ReadStreamEventsForwardAsync(streamName, nextSliceStart, sliceCount, true);

                foreach (var @event in currentSlice.Events)
                {
                    var myEvent = GetInstanceOfEvent<OrderMerchantFeesCalculatedEvent>(@event);


                    TransformEvent(myEvent);
                }

                nextSliceStart = currentSlice.NextEventNumber;

            } while (currentSlice.IsEndOfStream == false);
```